# How to run custom method when PowerShell script module is removed (to clean up after itself)

Tags: powershell

Is there a way for a PowerShell script module to run some code when it is removed?

Example:

```
Import-Module my-module.psm1
Remove-Module my-module
# At this point I want my-module.psm1 to be notified
# that it is being unloaded so it can run some clean up code.
```

My current use case is a module that adds a breakpoint and I want it call `Remove-PSBreakpoint` when the module is removed so it doesn't leave that clutter in scope.

Comment: [`PSModuleInfo.OnRemove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.psmoduleinfo.onremove.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at putting this line into your module.

```
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Module.OnRemove = { ## Some code }
```